# Issue regarding a lot of missing data and low event rate modeling

Tags: r, classification, missing-data, rare-events

My data has 192 variables in total (30k rows) and most of the variables have missing values. I want to do a classification model on this data e.g.

Only 3 dependent variables (excluding the customer ID) have 100% fill rate. Overall only 38 variables have less than 25% fill rate.

```
Code used:

for(i in colnames(model_data)) {
    NA_count[i] = sum(is.na(model_data[,i]))
}

per_NA = data.frame(NA_count/nrow(model_data))
```

I have never worked this sparse data before. In my earlier experiences, we used to do the imputation mostly by the mean/median. I have also heard people using clustering for imputation but this data is so sparse (for almost all variables) that i am not sure if clustering will help (neither will knn impute). Please advice what method should be used for the same.

Also the predictor variable has 7% event rate

```
prop.table(table(model_data_final$dependent))
         0          1 
0.92813333 0.07186667
```

Again this is a new territory for me as i have never worked with low event rate data. I read a lot of articles wherein people have mentioned various techniques such as weighted RF, oversampling etc. Can someone please give some intuition on the same?

And why can't we just create a model on the data as is and then while validation decide the threshold of probability based on the performance on validation data?

Can't post the data for privacy reasons.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try tree modelling (or random forrest) which can use data with a lot of missing.